# Why is S3 not triggering Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

An event should be triggered when I put a .png image into a combine-files bucket in the same region, but no event was triggered when I did that. Is there anything wrong/missing in my code?

Please help! I have spent a few hours on this! Greatly appreciated!

handler.py:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3') 

def combine_files(event, context):
    print('start')
    print(event)
```

serverless.yml:

```
service: combine-files

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
  region: us-west-2
  profile: serverless-admin
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action: 
        - "s3:*"
      Resource: "*"


custom:
  bucket: combine-files
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true

functions:
  combine_files:
    handler: handler.combine_files
    events:
      - s3:
        bucket: ${self:custom.bucket}
        event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
        rules:
          - suffix: .png
```

[The logs are in the link: (I have tested it a few times and added .png files to a bucket called combine_files a few times as well).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s62h.png)

Comment: When I tested it, "start" was printed out, but no event was printed.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible. Does the bucket get created?

Comment: Refresh your CloudWatch Logs view.

Comment: yes, the bucket has been created

Comment: I have refreshed it many times...

Comment: Can you post the CloudWatch Logs to your question, including START and END.

Comment: The logs you've attached were from testing in the Lambda console. {'key1': 'value1' ...} Is default test event in lambda console. Open Lambda console and check if there are event sources set to S3. Open S3 console and check if events are set there too.

Comment: Yes, that was the default event. I went to the console but didn't see any event sources set to S3 (except in my code). But, maybe just because I was not sure if I checked it correctly.